# How to count rows from two columns?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I try to create the function login that takes customer number(pnr) and password from same table. Its fine to create function but test crashes with following eror:
ORA-00904: "P_PASSWD": invalid identifier

```
create or replace function logga_in(
    p_pnr bankkund.pnr%type,
    p_passwd bankkund.passwd%type
    )
    return number
as
    v_resultat number(1);
begin
    select count(pnr) into v_resultat
    from   bankkund
    where  p_pnr = pnr
    and    p_passwd = passwd;

    return 1;
exception
    when no_data_found then
        return 0;
end;
```

Comment: Show the code that you are using to call the function.

Comment: SELECT logga_in(p_pnr,p_passwd)
FROM dual;

Comment: . . That is your problem.  The columns do not exist  in `dual`.

Comment: how can I test it then?

Comment: You can try bind variable like this: SELECT logga_in(:p_pnr,:p_passwd) FROM dual;

Comment: doesn't work :(

Comment: How you execute this select? If you use it in some plsql code then you can use local variable with values.

Comment: If there is a record with (for example) customer number `12345` and password `Kittens`, you would might call it with `select logga_in(12345, 'Kittens') from dual;` I'm not sure why it's a function though, and you probably shouldn't be storing passwords in plain text.

Comment: thank you William, this is exactly what my problem was :)))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is one other problem with your code not suggested in the comments, A `count` function from a `select into` will not raise a `NO_DATA_FOUND` exception. You may use an `IF` condition on count or do something like this, which is preferable

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION logga_in (
    p_pnr      bankkund.pnr%TYPE,
    p_passwd   bankkund.passwd%TYPE
) RETURN NUMBER AS
    v_resultat NUMBER(1);
BEGIN
SELECT 1       --do not use count if you wish to handle no_data_found
     INTO v_resultat FROM
        bankkund WHERE  pnr = p_pnr AND
        passwd = p_passwd
AND ROWNUM = 1; --Add this 
  RETURN 1;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN no_data_found THEN
        RETURN 0;
END;
```

Now, as far as calling the procedure is concerned, there are various options available including using bind variable

```
VARIABLE  p_pnr    number        --use the datatype of bankkund.pnr%TYPE
VARIABLE p_passwd VARCHAR2(10)  --use the datatype of bankkund.passwd
SELECT logga_in(:p_pnr,:p_passwd) FROM dual;
```

Or substitution variable

```
SELECT logga_in('&p_pnr','&p_passwd') FROM dual;
```

Give inputs when prompted.

Or use PL/SQL block

```
DECLARE
v_res INT;
v_pnr    bankkund.pnr%type    := 12892;  --or appropriate value
p_passwd bankkund.passwd%type := some_passwd';
BEGIN
   v_res := logga_in();
 If v_res = 1 THEN
  do_something_u_want; --call or execute appropriate action.
 END IF;
END;
/
```